# Postgres - Calculate distance with postgis

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

After looking for days, and try all what I find, I'm here to ask how to calculate the distance beetwen two points on Postgres with PostGis. I got a table called location. This table got a column "coordenate" of type point. When the user inserts a value on the application I need to get the locations ordered by the closes distance. I know I need to use ST_Distance, but everytime I try to cast the POINT of coordenate I can't. I need the result in Km.

I try:

`SELECT ST_Distance('POINT(0.0 0.0)', ST_GeomFromText(location.coordenate)) FROM app.location as location;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get distances in metres/kilometres you need to either transform your coordinates to a SRS that has metre as unit or, if possible, use `geography` instead of `geometry`, as `ST_Distance` returns the distance of two `geography` parameters in metres (1km = 1000m), e.g.

```
SELECT 
  ST_Distance(ST_MakePoint(0.0,0.0)::geography, coordenate::geography)/1000 
FROM app.location;
```

#### Casting `geometry` / `text` to `geography`

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=06a4a76849061389b4ede365ad62edc5)

```
CREATE TABLE location (gid int, coordenate geometry(point,4326));
INSERT INTO location VALUES
(1,'SRID=4326;POINT(10 10)'),(2,'SRID=4326;POINT(0.1 0.1)');

SELECT 
  gid, ST_AsText(coordenate),
  ST_Distance(ST_MakePoint(0.0,0.0)::geography, coordenate::geography)/1000  
FROM location
ORDER BY coordenate::geography <-> ST_MakePoint(0.0,0.0)::geography;

gid |   st_astext    |      ?column?      
-----+----------------+--------------------
   2 | POINT(0.1 0.1) | 15.690343289660001
   1 | POINT(10 10)   | 1565.1090992178902
(2 rows)
```

The operator `<->` means distance, so using it on the `ORDER BY` clause you can order the result set by distance.

#### Casting `point` to `geography`

The data type `point` is **not** a PostGIS data type, but a [`geometric data type`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-geometric.html#id-1.5.7.16.5) from PostgreSQL. In order to use `ST_Distance` you have to cast the points to either geometry or geography.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e5f01b38037fc45d73558c05d709c49d)

```
CREATE TABLE location (gid int, coordenate point);
INSERT INTO location VALUES
(1,point(10,10)),(2,point(0.1,0.1));

SELECT *,
  ST_Distance(
    ST_MakePoint(0.0,0.0)::geography, 
    ST_MakePoint(coordenate[0],coordenate[1])::geography)/1000 
FROM location
ORDER BY ST_MakePoint(coordenate[0],coordenate[1])::geography <-> ST_MakePoint(0.0,0.0)::geography;

 gid | coordenate |      ?column?      
-----+------------+--------------------
   2 | (0.1,0.1)  | 15.690343289660001
   1 | (10,10)    | 1565.1090992178902
(2 rows)
```

Further reading:

- [`ST_MakePoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html)
- [`ST_SetSRID`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html)
- [`ST_Distance`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html)

Comment: It works, the last question is how to cast the result to Km

Comment: @AlexanderÁlvarez by cast to km you mean how to convert metre to kilometer? -> `1000m = 1km`