# Postgres: Order coordinates points in a direction

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I ran into a problem in Postgres when I was working with spatial dates. I have a table with columns: object id and its coordinates (latitude and longitude, data type is geometry). I need to sort this data by coordinates in the direction from northwest to southeast. How can I do this? I suppose that of course I need to use an "order by" and an index. But which and how?

Comment: How do these coordinates look like once concatenated? Are they on a straight line?

Comment: no, this is not a straight line, but a field of points of one island. moving diagonally (from northwest to southeast) there may be a situation that several points will pretend to be next. so I think I need to add a condition, for example "show more northern points first"

Comment: @Wazyto welcome to SO. Wouldn't it suffice to simply order by the `x` axes?

Comment: Then it may be a situation that the most northeastern point will be defined as the most southeast. perhaps I need to try not order by axes, but order by distance from the northwestmost point? the distance to the southeast point should be the largest. am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You could create an envelope from the whole data set using [`ST_Envelope`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Envelope.html), and from there you could retrieve the corner you want as a reference - e.g. lower right corner. Using this reference point you can then order the geometries with the distance operator `<->`.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=10f8b7a72e5fcd9dee625f2215616b96)

```
CREATE TABLE t (gid int, geom geometry(point,4326));
    
INSERT INTO t VALUES 
(6,'SRID=4326;POINT(-4.3675 54.2428)'),
(5,'SRID=4326;POINT(-4.5488 54.3591)'),
(1,'SRID=4326;POINT(-4.5405 54.2974)'),
(7,'SRID=4326;POINT(-4.3098 54.2973)'),
(4,'SRID=4326;POINT(-4.4952 54.2742)'),
(2,'SRID=4326;POINT(-4.4568 54.2790)'),
(3,'SRID=4326;POINT(-4.4156 54.2509)');
```

[image]

The following [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) creates an envelope based on all points in table `t` (see envelope in the image above), retrieves the value of the lower right corner, and in the outer query it uses this reference point to order the records by distance.

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT 
    ST_SetSRID(
      ST_MakePoint(
        ST_XMax(ST_Envelope(ST_Union(geom))),
        ST_YMin(ST_Envelope(ST_Union(geom)))),
      4326) AS reference_point
  FROM t
)
SELECT 
  t.gid,
  ST_AsText(t.geom) AS geom, 
  ST_AsText(j.reference_point) AS reference_point,
  t.geom <-> j.reference_point AS distance_to_ref_point
FROM j,t
ORDER BY t.geom <-> j.reference_point;

 gid |          geom          |    reference_point     | distance_to_ref_point 
-----+------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------
   7 | POINT(-4.3098 54.2973) | POINT(-4.3098 54.2428) |   0.05449999999999733
   6 | POINT(-4.3675 54.2428) | POINT(-4.3098 54.2428) |   0.05769999999999964
   3 | POINT(-4.4156 54.2509) | POINT(-4.3098 54.2428) |   0.10610961313660537
   2 | POINT(-4.4568 54.279)  | POINT(-4.3098 54.2428) |   0.15139167744628546
   4 | POINT(-4.4952 54.2742) | POINT(-4.3098 54.2428) |   0.18804020846616745
   1 | POINT(-4.5405 54.2974) | POINT(-4.3098 54.2428) |    0.2370730899954694
   5 | POINT(-4.5488 54.3591) | POINT(-4.3098 54.2428) |    0.2657944506568918
```

Further reading:

- [Calculate distances with PostGIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69313318/2275388)